Using RequestFactory: compilation problem Migration Mojo gwt to TBroyer gwt plugin
Following the recommendations, I have two structural updates to make:

Switch from Mojo gwt to TBroyer gwt plugin

Use a separate server such as Tomcat for Super dev mode, abandoning the Embedded Jetty Server
I'm still on the first point...I integrated the TBroyer plugin, but I encounter the error below in the compilation phase when launching gwt:codeserver from Eclipse. I attach an extract of my POM file.
/home/williamd/j_env/workspace/simulator/src/main/java/com/e2b/simul/shared/SimulRequestFactory.java:[7,8] javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.e2b.simul.shared.SimulRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder


<plugin>
    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>        
    <configuration>
        <skipModule>true</skipModule> <!-- preserve existing simulator.gwt.xml ??? -->
        <startupUrls>app.jsp</startupUrls> <!-- customized landing page -->
        <launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</launcherDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
            
<!-- MAVEN COMPILER -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <annotationProcessors>
    <annotationProcessor>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfValidator</annotationProcessor>
    </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin> 
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
            <arguments>
            <argument>-cp</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ValidationTool</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
            <argument>com.e2b.simul.shared.SimulRequestFactory</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


Usually this means, that the annotation processor tries to create a file, that is already created.
